# How do I change the color of the side Alphabet in an indexed UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table view with an alphabetical index and am using the side alphabet to get through the list quickly.  For those not familiar, that uses this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
```

My problem is that my application has just been skinned black.  And so now it's hard to see the alphabet letters on the side.

I can't figure out how to change the color of the alphabet.  I'd like it to be 'white' if at all possible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From what I can tell unfortunately it is not possible to customize the color of the text displayed in the index, the closest I've been able to come is being able to modify the background color and the font of the index.

There is some code in the iPhone Developers cookbook by Erica Sadun which shows how to access the UITableViewIndex view (an undocumented class).  You can find the reference to it on page 175 of the book if you have it. Which gives access to the background color and the font.  You can see an unofficial document related to this class [here](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs220/interface_u_i_table_view_index.html).

**WARNING** This is undocumented use of an undocumented class so you need to be cautious about using it.

Here is a code snippet from the cookbook with minor modifications:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

  for(UIView *view in [tv subviews])
  {
    if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
    {

      [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
      [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    }
  }

  //rest of cellForRow handling...

}
```

This illustrates how you can access and the UITableViewIndex view and modify it in some aspects.  It looks like the view doesn't have any subviews so it is likely doing some custom drawing with the array of index titles.

It's not perfect but hopefully it helps a little.

Paul

Comment: The above iteration can be implemented in the method:
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;

This will avoid repeating the iteration everytime you scroll the tableView.

Comment: This method just changed the background color of the indexes for me. What if I want to change the color of fonts only and not their background?

Comment: @DipDhingani to change the color of the fonts (to red in this example), use this: [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: Since UIKit component view hierarchies have been known to change in the past, if you're going to use this method then I'd recommend searching the whole subview tree (rather than the first level). A recursive way to do so can be found [here](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/using-private-ios-apis/).

Comment: how can we set  it [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

Comment: This is very fragile, and it depends on Apple never ever changing the `UITableView` view hierarchy

Comment: @paulthenerd this line gives error [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];   //view does not has any setFont method

Comment: [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];  setFont not working for me.. How can we set font size

Answer (score 60):

if your minimum iOS version is newer than 6.0, you can use `sectionIndexColor`  property of `UITableView`.

> The color to use for the table view’s index text.
>
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexColor
>
> Discussion:
>
> Table views can display an index along the side of the view, making it
> easier for users to navigate the contents of the table quickly. This
> property specifies the color to use for text displayed in this region.

---

**Update date 2014.1.13**

I find an open source third party library:[GDIIndexBar](https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar) to help custom the index appearance.

Comment: Perfect... Works like a charm :)

Comment: Cool.  I'm not sure why, but in iOS 8.1, the default index background & text color was blue-on-blue.  Thanks to your tip, I could change the "self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor" to a white background.

Answer (score 21):

This can be easily changed in the interface builder for the UITableView - No need to use undocumented classes?

See screenshot below, as you can see the font colour and the background colour can be changed too. Job's a good'n!

[image]

Answer (score 18):

For iOS7 or Higher:

```
self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem and just found out a way of doing this, though this is using undocumented classes and methods so think one extra time before trying to upload it to the App Store.
I should say that i've only tried this with iOS5 so I don't know if it will work for previous versions.

I borrowed and modified the Erica Saunders cookbook example so that it now changes the text color to red:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

  for(UIView *view in [tv subviews])
  {
    if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
    {
      [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
  }

  //rest of cellForRow handling...

}
```

Answer (score 11):

We have successfully used the following code:

```
for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews]) {
    if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:)]) {
        [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```

which works fine - it's very similar to Mooglas answer - but refrains from using the word "UITableViewIndex".

Answer (score 9):

You can set the tint color for the tableView.

```
[[UITableView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5:**

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = .red
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Works in Swift 5 too

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to change the color of the index Alphabet.

In your header file, declare your UITableView as a property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
```

Then in your implementation file's viewDidAppear, use the following line:

```
//Change the color of the UITableView index color
_mainTable.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best solution I've found to adjust the background colour of the index bar on the side. It works in iOS7 and probably iOS6.

Add this to your viewDidLoad

```
if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexColor:)]) {
    _tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

The first one is the default colour, the second is the background colour when you are scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Make a mutable array to contain the alternate title label
In

```
-(NSArray * )sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView * )tableView
```

return an array of @" " where the number of spaces between the quotes determines the width of the hi-lighted scroller.
Have "sectionIndexTitlesForTableView" call an update label function.
In that function remove all the labels in the array you created earlier from their superviews Then create and add however many labels are needed. Then add them to the table's superview.

These are the lines required to place the labels in the right place.

```
rect.origin.x = table.frame.origin.x+table.frame.size.width-rect.size.width-2;
rect.origin.y = 5+table.frame.origin.y+counter *(280-rect.size.height-([customIndexLabels count]-1))/([customIndexLabels count]-1);
if ([customIndexLabels lastObject]==thisLabel)
{
   rect.origin.y-=10;
}
```

Hope that helps.  It's not perfect I just don't care enough to fix it myself
The main problem is that the spacing of the last label is not uniform.

Answer (score -2):

Swift edition for undocumented font change:

```
extension NSObject {

    class func objectClassName() -> String {

        let classLongName = reflect(self.self).summary;

        let tokens = classLongName.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

        if let typeName = tokens.last {

            return typeName
        }

        return NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)
    }
}

func changeSectionIndexFont(tableView: UITableView) -> Void {

        let realSubviews = tableView.subviews as! [UIView]

        for subview in realSubviews {

            if subview.dynamicType.objectClassName() == "UITableViewIndex" {

                subview.setValue(UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 10), forKey: "font")
            }
        }
    }
```