# How to set a tint color for the section index of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, colors

Is there any way to customize the grey color of the alphabetic section index of a UITableView?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since iOS 6.0 it's actually possible to customize the tint color for the section index. The relevant properties are: `sectionIndexColor` and `sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor`.

iOS 7 added `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` which specifies the background color for the section index while **not** being touched.

Answer (score 4):

It's maybe a bit late but as I had to deal with this problem with iOS 7 I might help you.

From iOS 7 there is a new method called :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexColor
```

Now you can set the color to use for the background of the table view’s section index while not being touched.

As a proper code to use with iOS 6 and 7 you could :

```
self.friendsTableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor aColor]; // background color while the index view is being touched
if ([self.friendsTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(sectionIndexBackgroundColor)])
    self.friendsTableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor aColor]; // background color while the index view is NOT touched at all
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the UITableView's [appearance proxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to set these:

`[UITableView appearance].sectionIndexColor = [UIColor myTintColor];`

Answer (score 1):

in short:
you can change the fontsize and the complete backround (not the rounded one)
more isn't possible.

Comment: you can do more actually - see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412958/554760