# Changing UITableView "BackgroundColor" of Index-Component

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm not sure if my title is a bit "crappy" to say the least, but let me explain my issue here.
I'm having a Table with about 300 Entries, sorted and sectioned alphabetically. 
The tableview shows the alphabetical slider to the right (just like in the "contacts"-application in iphone) "untouched" it looks very nice (grey font, my tablecells are blue), but when the index-scroller is being touched it gets this grey "shadow" around it that makes the letters almost dissapear.

is there any way to change the font-color of the indexes or the color of the background ?

i hope i could explain my problem in an understandable way.

cheers and thanx for your help

sam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview

Comment: for this please once read this ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview?lq=1

Comment: Please read this ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no "supported" way to change the appearance of the "scrubber".

Comment: damn it.. at least i know how to call it now :). thx. what about the unsupported way then?

Comment: Depends on how the scrubber is created. You can always traverse the view hierarchy. It's a functional, yet volatile hack.