# Possible to move UITableView's index?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I'm using the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` method for my custom UITableView, to display A-Z on the side of my table. However, the standard view of this doesn't match the style of the table. Is there a way to change this, or at least move the index a little?

Here's how it overlaps:

[image]

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/750119/143

Answer (score 1):

I too tried the same thing..but not succedded.
but as a workaround we can introduce spaces before the text which we want to display as a section header, so that we can start index with some gap.