# How to change font color of section index titles

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to display an indexed table view.

By default, section index titles have gray color.

How do I change their color?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview

Comment: I think u didnt get my question. i dont want to change section header view but the color of section index titles that appear on the right hand side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i read the wrong question just now.

if you mean the A-Z index that let you navigate the section title of the tableview, then it cannot be change,not possible for the moment. Or you can create your own.

**FOLLOW UP**

> **This only apply to before iOS6**. For iOS6 and above please refer to HpTerm's answer.

Comment: It is possible. See HpTerm's answer below.

Comment: +1 simply to support you. People should not downvote you. Your answer was right prior to iOS6 and this does not deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 76):

**EDIT/FOLLOW UP iOS7** (Sept. 2013) Read answer of Graham Perks for a follow up on iOS7 where he explains about `sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor` and `sectionIndexBackgroundColor`

---

Follow up (Sept. 2012) of this question for future readers.

Since iOS 6 it is now possible to change the index color text and background. Two functions are available for that (see iOS 6 documentation).

---

**sectionIndexColor**

The color to use for the table view’s index text.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexColor
```

Table views can display an index along the side of the view, making it easier for users to navigate the contents of the table quickly. This property specifies the color to use for text displayed in this region.

Availability : Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Declared In : UITableView.h

---

**sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor**

The color to use for the table view’s index background area.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor
```

Table views can display an index along the side of the view, making it easier for users to navigate the contents of the table quickly. This property specifies the color to display in the background of the index when the user drags a finger through it.

Availability : Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Declared In : UITableView.h

Comment: `sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor` is the background color while tracking with your finger. In iOS7, to change the normal background color, use `sectionIndexBackgroundColor`.

Comment: Great follow up for iOS 7.0. Save me some headache.

Comment: @GrahamPerks I am getting rewards (+1) for the follow up on iOS7. But I don't deserve these rewards as it is your follow up. You should write an answer/follow up on that and I'll remove my reference to that so you get the rewards.

Comment: OK, done :)  Your answer set me on the right path, thanks so much for that.

Answer (score 15):

**Add the below code in your `viewDidLoad` (for swift):**

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Answer (score 13):

In **iOS 7**, to change the **normal background color** use the `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` property.

`sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor` is the **background color while tracking** with your finger.

(Thanks to HpTerm for the initial pointers which work great on iOS 6.)

Answer (score 5):

optimized way to change index section background color and text color

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:162.0/255.0 blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableSection"]]];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview) indicates an "undocumented" way of doing it. I used it in production code, it works (not tested for iOS under 5.0).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can not change the color of the index.

Comment: You can. See HpTerm's answer.

Comment: @JoshuaDance It's not fair to downgrade this answer since it was provided in 2011 when iOS 6.0 is not out then. This answer is still correct at that point in time.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Sorry if it seemed like I did. I just commented on it so those coming after would know it is now possible. Still a rookie here on SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a bit late, but for everyone who's searching for an answer, here the Swift code

```
for view in tableView.subviews {
    if view.respondsToSelector("setIndexColor:") {
        view.performSelector("setIndexColor:", withObject: UIColor.yourColor())
    }
}
```

Then if you want to get the section index as view and do what you want with it, here it is:

```
for view in tableView.subviews {
    NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "UITableViewIndex" {
        // do what you want
        // e.g: view.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change table view tint colour to your desired colour.