# UITableView section index background?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

[image]

How do I get rid of the white color in the section index? When I remove the section index entirely, this is how it looks: 
[image]

So is the section index causing the problem? But when I build the iPhone version with the same exact code, I get this:

[image]

Nevermind, I found out the solution. Too long to type out but I fixed it. It had to do with the autosizing masks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the autoresizing mask in the Custom Cell objects I was using (using interface builder for building custom cells). Check those first.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on your solution, I'm having the same problem right now? Thanks

Comment: Each UIView has an autoresizingMask property (See documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask ). Basically I had the wrong autoresizing mask set for each cell and it wasn't autoresizing properly when changing orientations.

Comment: My problem is that with the iPhone in portrait, and after setting the autoresizing for x/y on the custom cell, I still get the white space on the right hand side. What exact resizing settings did you apply to your cell and subviews?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to allocate a new `UIView` to the cell's `backgroundView`.

Comment: I've tried to change autoresizing masks for the cells but nothing changes. I always have the white background sections index bar on the right. This is a problem I have with iOS7 and I didn't have with iOS6 though, on both iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Table View has delegates to edit section index font color as well as background colour.

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexColor:)]) {
    self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:0.7];
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

also one of the solution:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    // Some code here

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It changes the background of the cell but not the background of the sectionIndex bar.

Comment: Yes, this is true... To tell the truth, I don't have this problem now... even when I removed all my code o_O

Comment: I have this problem with iOS7

Answer (score 1):

Even though you found the answer, as a follow up note that in new iOS you can now change the section index properties, look at my answer here

[How to change font color of section index titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662301/how-to-change-font-color-of-section-index-titles/12617264#12617264)

in your case use sectionIndexBackgroundColor to change the background color

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *sectionIndexBackgroundColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - section indexes can't be styled (except maybe by something really hackish like looping through the view hierarchy to find the index view and then mangling it somehow).

Either create your own index view by overlaying buttons in front of the tableview, or live without the index.