# Change Table View Index Background Colour

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with an Index. When a user runs their finger over the index column by default it is selected with a grey semi transparent background (see contact application for example). How can I change this background colour? Or alternatively can I simply prevent the background colour from displaying at all?

Is it also possible to change the text colour of the letters in the index?

Any help much appreciated :)

Steve

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the color of the side Alphabet in an indexed UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview)