# How to change color of UITable view indexbar selected index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `UITableView` index bar how to change color of selected index on index bar

I use code like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:   (NSInteger)index
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i< [dataArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *letterString = [alphabetsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([letterString isEqualToString:title])
        {
            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            lblSelectedIndex.text = [alphabetsArray objectAtIndex:index];

           break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

it scroll table on that selected index charecter but i need to change color of that selected charecter.Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the color of the side Alphabet in an indexed UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is not official Apple available to do that. And Apple may reject you app if you do that. If you just wants to customize `indexBar` then below library may help you (It can't customize what you currently wants).

You can use custom library `GDIIndexBar` (iOS 6+), which you can customize.

https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar

Here's sample snippet for `GDIIndexBar`

```
GDIIndexBar *indexBar = [[GDIIndexBar alloc] initWithTableView:tableView];
indexBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:indexBar];
```

You can customize as per follows:

```
[[GDIIndexBar appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[GDIIndexBar appearance] setTextShadowColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[[GDIIndexBar appearance] setTextFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:11.5];
```