# How can I to set font size for UITableView right sectionIndex?

Tags: ios, uitableview, fonts

How can I to set font size for the `UITableView` right sectionIndex?

[image: right sectionIndex]

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/758798/5362916

Comment: @UmaMadhavi it's no use

Comment: show your some code @CoderYL

Comment: sorry,don't have any meaningful code,just want to set the font of sectionIndex@MayankPatel

Comment: @CoderYL you should have to refer uma Madhavi's link

Comment: check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833038/4025645

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this solution, this will definitely help you ->

Step 1) Add this method in your class

- (void)setUITableViewSectionIndexFontSize:(UITableView*)tableView{
    //UI the index view
    for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews]) {
        if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:)]) {
            [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor grayColor]];

            if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setFont:)]) {
                [view performSelector:@selector(setFont:) withObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];
                [view performSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor blueColor]];

            }
        }
    }
}

Step 2) Now add this line just before [tableView reloadData] line ->

[self setUITableViewSectionIndexFontSize:tableView];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This solution is close but if there's a search field in the tableview, the size is not updated after pressing cancel in the search field. Cant figure out how to make it work.